# Stuck on creating a preliminary tic tac toe board that places an 'x' in square you click. How do I combine previous board with current board?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This was for an hw assignment, but it's already past due, and my solution was wrong because I changed the innerHTML of whichever square was clicked. I'm not sure how to write this code. Here's the file that uses the hook:

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import React from 'react';
import {useState,useRef,setState} from 'react';
import { ChangeBoard,MakeBoard } from './Board.js';

function App() {
  const [board, setBoard] = useState([]);
  function onClickButton(event){
    var clickedId = event.target.id;
    setBoard(prevBoard => [...prevBoard,clickedId]);
  }
  return (
    <div onClick={onClickButton}>
    <MakeBoard />
    {board.map(id => <ChangeBoard index={id} />)}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And here's the file that renders the board:

```
import React from 'react';
import './Board.css';

export function MakeBoard(){
    return(
        <div className="board">
            <div className="box" id='1' ></div>
            <div className="box" id='2' ></div>
            <div className="box" id='3' ></div>
            <div className="box" id='4' ></div>
            <div className="box" id='5' ></div>
            <div className="box" id='6' ></div>
            <div className="box" id='7' ></div>
            <div className="box" id='8' ></div>
            <div className="box" id='9' ></div>
        </div>
        )
        
}

export function ChangeBoard(index){
    console.log(index['index']);
    document.getElementsByClassName('box')[index['index']-1].innerHTML='x';
    return(null);
}
```

Our professor wants us to only use functions, as he reasons that they're more modern and will be the future. I understand that the hook, in the first pair of bracketes, is the object and function that manipulates that object. And I understand that the data structure (the array) I used is being populated by all the previous boards and indexes of clicked squares. But how would I combine the previousBoard with the currentBoard. That's where I get stuck. And that's why I had to make a separate function, ChangeBoard, that changes the innerHTML. I'm not sure how I can just use MakeBoard to keep populating the board with x's until all 9 squares are full.

Comment: You need to read on at least some basic react docs https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html. Your example is wrong on so many levels, starting with having side effects in components and ending with storing data in html.. In react, you need to store your program state in, well, state, and render html elements from that state. Any change to program (clicking a cell) should change app state, which will update html

Comment: To add onto what Max is saying, the idea with react is to modify the state, which causes the app to redraw. State is essentially just the variables you use as part of output. In this case, your state would contain which boxes were checked so you know what to output. If you prefer video, this one seems to do a pretty good job at walking you through an example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=35lXWvCuM8o

Comment: Like I said, we can't use classes or constructors. So no 'this' and no 'setState'.

Comment: @DerekH Thanks, I'll give it a watch.